# Ngx-toastr, Unable to focus on it

Tags: frontend, angular12, ngxs, ngx-toastr

I have purchased this theme for angular and they have changed the default view of ngx-toastr.
Everything is working fine but they have disabled focus on toast because of that I can't perform any kind of action on it. I have tried a lot of properties but couldn't find the one that makes it non-focusable.

```
        // disableTimeOut: true,
        timeOut: 10000,
        positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
        closeButton: true,
        progressBar: true,
        // tapToDismiss: true,
        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
        // preventDuplicates: true,
    }),
```

These are the default properties, I have given my toastr. And from what I learned about this theme there is some change in,"
`ToastrModule` " If anybody knows how to make it focusable ping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS of course.
`.toastr { pointer-events: none; }` 
by default this prop is `auto` but someone updated it in custom css files.
for those who don't know what it does, it ignores all the events that can accur while you focus on the element with your mouse or pointing device.